# Plone 3.1.2 - TypeError in ATDocument.getText() method

Tags: python, plone, typeerror, zope

My task is to unload content from a Plone 3.1.2 website and load information about the content to an SQL database + file system

I've recreated the website, got access to ZODB and recreated object and folder structure. I am also able to read properties of folders, files and documents. I can't get the .getText() method of ATDocument to work. The Traceback looks like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\jan\Eclipse_workspace\Plone\start.py", line 133, in ? 
    main() 
  File "C:\Users\jan\Eclipse_workspace\Plone\start.py", line 118, in main 
    print dokument.getText() 
  File "e:\Program Files\Plone 3\Data\Products\Archetypes\ClassGen.py", line 54, in generatedAccessor
  File "e:\Program Files\Plone 3\Data\Products\Archetypes\BaseObject.py", line 828, in Schema 
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <ATDocument at /*object_path*>, <InterfaceClass Products.Archetypes.interfaces._schema.ISchema>)
```

I suspect that there is a problem with connecting the object to interface ISchema, but I've never worked with Plone before and don't know it's object model.

Any suggestions what might be wrong or missing, how can I fix it and/or what to do next? I suspect that I have to connect ISchema interface class with this object somehow, but have no idea where to start. Any suggestions?

I'll be greatful for any help since I'm stuck for 2 days now and not moving forward.

I know nothing about ZCML format or how to edit it. 
Because after `>>> print dokument.getText()` in debug mode the script jumps to `makeMethod()` method in Generator class I assume that the script doesn't execute `.getText()` but tries to create this method instead.

Since `inspect.getmembers(dokument)` returns a `getText()` method I'm really confused.
Do you know in which ZCML file might be related to ATDocument class? Or where can I look for any information on this subject?

My start.py file doesn't do much else than the following imports:

```
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
from ZODB.DB import DB
from OFS.Application import Application
from BTrees import OOBTree
from Products.CMFPlone.Portal import PloneSite
```

then it gets access to dokument object and tries to execute `.getText()`

Edit 213-03-26 15:27 (GMT):

About the .zcml files
The site I've received was 3 folders: Products (extracted to `\Plone 3\Data`), lib and package-includes.

Inside the lib there is python folder containing 3 subfolders: 'common', 'abc' and 'def' (names changed not to release client's information). Each of these subfolders contains a configure.zcml file, one of these also includes override.zcml file.

In the folder package-includes there are 4 files, each of them 1 line long. They contain the following lines:

```
<include package="abc" file="configure.zcml" />
<include package="def" file="overrides.zcml" />
<include package="common" file="configure.zcml" />
<include package="def" file="configure.zcml" />
```

These zcml files are not copied at the moment. Where can I copy these to have these imported?

Comment: From the looks of your traceback you rigged things up in your own setup without using the Zope scaffolding? I'd say you didn't load the ZCML registrations, of which there are a lot, but it is hard to tell without seeing your `start.py` code.

Comment: thanks for your input @Martijn. I still can't get it to work tho, and  I know nothing about ZCML format or how to edit it.

Comment: The ZCML format is just XML that defines configuration for the server, including registering components and adapters. You do not need to edit it, just *load* it. That can be complex, and I am wondering what you are doing not using the Zope infrastructure already in place. Hence my request for your `start.py` source, so we can help you do this correctly.

Comment: @Martijn I've tried to enter a little longer comment, but it turned out that I can't so I've edited my original post.

Comment: Which is what I wanted you to do in the first place! It's *always* fine to edit your question to add detail requested in comments.

Comment: How did you install the Plone software to import here? Is there perhaps a buildout, can you run the site itself at all?

Comment: I've received 3 folders (Products, lib and package-includes where there are 4 zcml files) and data.fs file. I've then downloaded Plone 3.1.2, extracted lib and Products folders and extracted the zcml files to overwrite other files. Now that I review it this is where I might have made an error, but the plone site itself worked so I did push through. I'll write more about these zcml files in my question in a moment.

Comment: I *do not need to see those ZCML files*. I need to know how you ran the Plone site itself. The commands used.

Comment: To make it more explicit: if you can run `bin/instance fg` or similar to get the site running, there is a *far easier path* to what you want.

Comment: I run the site through Plone Controller on localhost, however in start.py script I don't run the site, just access the application object in zodb directly

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: windows 7, I run it as local server and then I can access the site through a browser

Comment: There is a [experimental buildout-based installer](http://plone.org/products/plone/releases/3.1.7) for Plone 3.1; can you try that one for me? I am not 100% certain where to find the scripts you want to have in the 'regular' Windows installer.

Comment: I'm downloading, however the zodb file is 4gb so it will take about 10 to 15 minutes for me to set up the site.

Comment: Done. I've extracted Products to parts\instance\Products, my lib folder to parts\instance\lib, but don't know where to extract data.fs (zodb file) and the 4 .zcml files I got.

Comment: We are overstretching the comments here. Since you do not yet have enough reputation to use the Stack Overflow Chat, why not come over to the [Plone IRC channel](http://plone.org/support/chat) and we can continue there. My nick there is MJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing component registrations, usually registered when loading the ZCML files in a site.

You want to end up with the possibility to run `bin/instance run yourscript.py` instead, which leaves all the tedious site and ZCML loading to Zope.

Once you have that running reliably, you can then access the site in a script that sets up the local component manager and a security manager:

```
from zope.app.component.hooks import setSite
from Testing.makerequest import makerequest
from AccessControl.SecurityManagement import newSecurityManager

site_id = 'Plone'     # adjust to match your Plone site object id.
admin_user = 'admin'  # usually 'admin', probably won't need adjusting
app = makerequest(app)
site = app[site_id]
setSite(site)
user = app.acl_users.getUser(admin_user).__of__(site.acl_users)
newSecurityManager(None, user)

# `site` is your Plone site, now correctly set up
```

Save this script somewhere, and run it with:

```
bin/instance run path/to/yourscript.py
```

Comment: @toutpt: We've been helping the OP in the Plone #IRC channel to get the `bin/instance` part running.

Comment: I've finally managed to do what you told me to and `ATDocument.getText()` works like a charm. Thanks you SO much for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are starting your task is not the good one.
You are trying to use the API without the framework setup. It's possible but you have to know the framework very well (load the persistent sitemanager, ...)

You should add a 'browser view' and call it to export your content.

You can do that by:

- create your own addon and install it
- modify an installed addon (hey it's temporary work after all)

You will find documentation about browserview and plone at http://developer.plone.org

Sorry but if you need to develop for Plone you will need to read a bit about all this.